# Obtain the value laravel sets for the laravel_session cookie

Tags: laravel

I'm working on an app that uses laravel as the backend, the login form works through ajax and the frontend is loaded locally so it's a cross domain, the problem is laravel doesn't set the cookie on the client side so the user doesn't stay logged in.

I'm thinking on getting the cookie manually and injecting it on the global ajax headers for the app but I can't find how laravel converts the session id to the giant string that sets as a cookie, how can i obtain it or how can i convert the session id to the value?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `domain` variable in your `session.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => null,
```

Here you can set the `domain` to your local domain.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a workaround, generated a random hashed token and stored as key on redis with the id of the user as value, sent it back and stored it on the local storage in the front end, then set it on the global ajax header, and the server side just calls

```
Auth::loginUsingid($id)
```

from the token value sent by the client on every request, it's messy but it works around the problem of cross domains